# Call MainActivity function from Scrollview class

Tags: android, class, android-context, scroller

I'm new to android programming. I encountered the following problem: I've a main activity where I call reading procedures(json and image). I want to add an infinite scrolling to my activity so I've written a function to update the screen (list). Now I need to call it from the ScrollView class, but I can't declare static this method, because of the number of variables that I should change.

HOME ACTIVITY

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTaskComplete {

    LinearLayout wrapper = null;
    Context context = this;

    public Bitmap imageHandler;

    @Override
    public void callBackFunction(Bitmap image) {

        imageHandler = image;

    }

    public class Post{

        String id;
        String title;
        String description;
        String release;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getRelease() {
            return release;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setRelease(String release) {
            this.release = release;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {

            return id;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        //OUTER
        RelativeLayout outer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.outer);

        //SCROLLER
        Scroller scroller = new Scroller(this, this);
        scroller.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        //WRAPPER
        wrapper = new LinearLayout(this);
        wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        outer.addView(scroller);
        scroller.addView(wrapper);

        list();

    }

    public void list(){


        String result = null;
        ArrayList<Post> focusOn = new ArrayList<Post>();


        try {
            URL address = new URL("http://www.youth-stories.com/api/all.php");
            URLDataReader reader = new URLDataReader(context);
            result = reader.execute(address).get();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            String success = (String) obj.getString("success");
            JSONArray records = obj.getJSONArray("records");

            int start = (Globals.PAGE * Globals.STEP);
            int limit = start + Globals.STEP;
            //for(int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
            for(int i = start ; i < limit; i++) {
                Post tmp = new Post();
                tmp.setId(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                tmp.setTitle(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                tmp.setDescription(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("contents"));
                tmp.setRelease(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("data_post"));
                focusOn.add(tmp);
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //wrapper
        LinearLayout container = wrapper;

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("loading contents, please wait..");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        for(int i = 0; i < focusOn.size(); i++) {
            //item
            LinearLayout item = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            String select = focusOn.get(i).getId();
            item.setId(new Integer(select));
            item.setClickable(true);

            //setUp new activity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeOnSelect.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int id = item.getId();
            String strid = new Integer(id).toString();
            bundle.putString("id",  strid);
            bundle.putString("title",   focusOn.get(i).getTitle());
            bundle.putString("contents", focusOn.get(i).getDescription());
            bundle.putString("release", focusOn.get(i).getRelease());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            container.addView(item);
            item.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            item.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 40);
            item.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.postlayout);

            //image
            ImageView asset = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            URL address = null;

            try {

                address = new URL("http://www.youth-stories.com/public/admin/CH_FocusOn/images/" + focusOn.get(i).getId() + "_thumb2.jpg");
                URLImageReader reader = new URLImageReader(this, this, asset, dialog, i, focusOn.size());
                reader.execute(address);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            item.addView(asset);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgSettings = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);

            asset.setLayoutParams(imgSettings);
            asset.setPadding(50,0,0,0);

            //inside
            LinearLayout contents = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            contents.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            contents.setPadding(55, 0, 100, 0);
            item.addView(contents);
            //title
            TextView title = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            title.setText(focusOn.get(i).getTitle());
            title.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title);
            contents.addView(title);
            //description
            TextView description = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            description.setText(focusOn.get(i).getDescription());
            description.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.description);
            contents.addView(description);
            //date
            TextView date = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            date.setText(focusOn.get(i).getRelease());
            date.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.description);
            contents.addView(date);
            //div
            LinearLayout div = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            div.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 40));
            div.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            container.addView(div);
        }


    }

}
```

SCROLLER CLASS

```
public class Scroller extends ScrollView {

    Context cnt = null;
    Activity activity = null;

    public Scroller(Context context, Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        cnt = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        //TOP
        if (t == 0) {
            //Toast.makeText(cnt, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //BOTTOM
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY() + view.getTop()));
        if (diff == 0) {
            Globals.PAGE++;
            Toast.makeText(cnt, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Resources

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want infinite scrolling right ?

Comment: yeah i want to add items when the screen scroll down

Comment: i cant believe there's no way to call main activity function from scrollviw class. it should be useless

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an infinite scrolling in your Application, you could achieve it through a ListView, Here is some tutorial on How to make Infinite Scrolling ListView on Android

LINK 1:

> https://andytsui.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/tutorial-infinite-scroll-endless-list-view-with-android-binding/

LINK 2:

> http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html

Comment: so thereis not way to call a main activity function?

Comment: its possible to pass the whole activity as argument?

Comment: this could also achieve through local broadcast recievers, check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026515/how-to-use-interface-to-communicate-between-two-activities

Answer (score 0):

solved:
interface implemented in the main activity:

```
public void onScrollChanged(Scroller scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
   // Toast.makeText(this,"sl",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    list();
}
```

interface:

```
public interface ScrollViewListener {

    void onScrollChanged(Scroller scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);

}
```

Scrollview class:

```
public class Scroller extends ScrollView {

    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

    public Scroller(Context context, ScrollViewListener mlistener) {
        super(context);
        this.scrollViewListener = mlistener;

    }

    public Scroller(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public Scroller(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
        this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        //TOP
        if (t == 0) {
            //Toast.makeText(cnt, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //BOTTOM
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY() + view.getTop()));
        if (diff == 0) {
            Globals.PAGE++;
            //Toast.makeText(cnt, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);


        }
    }

}
```