# Custom Listener using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, listener

I have created a custom listener using the following code in EditTransactionActivity:

```
private OnTransactionUpdateListener mTranUpdateListener;


public interface OnTransactionUpdateListener {
    public void transactionUpdated(Tran tran);
}

public void setTransactionUpdateListener(OnTransactionUpdateListener listener) {
    this.mTranUpdateListener = listener;
}
```

I call the method using:

```
mTranUpdateListener.transactionUpdated(mTransaction);
```

In TransactionDetailActivity I have implemented the class with the following method:

```
@Override
public void transactionUpdated(Tran tran) {
    this.mTransaction = tran;
}
```

The problem I have is that the listener has not been set, since I am loading EditTransactionActivity using an Intent, how do I set the listener?  I have no instance of the object to set.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                EditTransactionActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(
bundle.putSerializable("transaction_key", mTransaction);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You want communication between two activities if I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, when I save data in EditTransactionActivity, I call finish() but I want to pass an object back first.

Comment: Modify the model solution from the following solution to use your interface.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026515/how-to-use-interface-to-communicate-between-two-activities

Comment: Basically you would want to make a singleton to hold your interface

Comment: There's three classes there though, my interface is within one of my activities.

Comment: Yes. You can put your interface in a standalone file if you want and make it public. It doesn't matter.

Comment: If I create an instance of the activity and set the listener onCreate, this still doesn't work when the activity is loaded through the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it passing the Intent back through onActivityResult().  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some notes about your code should be correct

1) You can't pass `interface` (behaviour) directly to bundle as `Serializable` object, you should pass object of a class, and this class must implement `Serializable` and `OnTransactionUpdateListener` interfaces.

2) Even if you do the first note, the listener will not be set, you should manually do it in `onCreate` method of the activity to get the `Serializable` object from the extras and update the listener variable.

```
// psudu code
// in onCreate method of the EditTransactionActivity we will read and set listener
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null &&
    getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("transaction_key")) {

    Serializable serializableObject= getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("transaction_key");
    if (serializableObjecte instanceof OnTransactionUpdateListener) {
          mTranUpdateListener= (OnTransactionUpdateListener) serializableObject;
    }
}
```

Note: you can use `Parcelable` interface instead of using `Serializable` interface. `Parcelable` is an Android specific interface where you implement the serialization yourself. It was created to be far more efficient that `Serializable`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: You'll get a classcast exception?  Listener - Transaction

Comment: You are right so we should check it first. (I have updated the code)

Comment: Where is the NullPointerException exactly?