# How to perform a method of another class when I click the Accept Button of my Dialog which is located in another class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-alertdialog

This snippet here is in my MainActivity.java which calls the "newdrawing()" method of my class named tools.java.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String color = null;

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.newdraw_a:
            tools buttons = new tools(this);
            buttons.newdrawing();
            break;
```

The "newdrawing()" method is a dialog which asks the user to add another drawing or cancel. When the user clicks "Accept", I want to call a method from another class named "canvas_class.java".

```
    public class tools extends View{

    public canvas_class drawing;

    public tools(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

    public void newdrawing(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
        newDialog.setTitle("New Drawing?");
        newDialog.setMessage("You will overwrite all your current drawings. Are you sure you want to add another drawing?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.dismiss();
                drawing.newdrawing();
            }
        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();

    }

}
```

Now, I want to ask what is wrong with my code in tools.java that it force closes when I click Accept. Thank you.

My canvas_class looks like this

```
public class canvas_class extends View {

private Canvas drawCanvas;

public canvas_class(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

public void newdrawing(){
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();

}
```

Comment: Use interface or broadcast listener, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026515/how-to-use-interface-to-communicate-between-two-activities but search more before asking questions, since this type of ques have lot of answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Thank you Brendon. But, can you please explain further? Newbie here ^_^

Comment: If you have a null pointer exception this is because 'drawing' member is not initialized.  You need to pass an instance in the constructor, or do a new inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably getting a NullPointerException as

drawing is null so it throws a exception, please initialize the

canvas_class drawing variable so that it doesnt throw a exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if 'this.attrs' is legal, perhaps someone else could help you, but your constructor for the 'tools' class could be something like this:

```
public tools(Context context) {
   super(context);
   drawing = new canvas_class(context, this.attrs);
}
```

And is better to name classes with uppercase:

```
class Tools
class CanvasClass
```

I hope this helps.