# Call a interface method from Android activity class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Below is the interface class

```java
public interface ICasAuthentication {
    String getTicketGrantingTicket(String username, String password, String hostUrl, String casUrl);
}
```

This is the class method which implements the interface.

```java
public class CasAuthentication  implements ICasAuthentication{
    private IServiceHandler _iServiceHandler = null;
    public CasAuthentication(IServiceHandler iServiceHandler)
    {
        this._iServiceHandler = iServiceHandler;

    }
}

 public String getTicketGrantingTicket(String username, String password, String hostUrl, String casUrl) {
        Map<String,String> postData = new HashMap<String,String>();
        postData.put("username", username);
        postData.put("password", password);
        postData.put("hostUrl", hostUrl);
       String response = _iServiceHandler.makeServiceCallString(casUrl, MethodTypes.POST.toString(), postData);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I have the android activity class as code below. I want to call `ICasAuthentication` method from my android class. How can i achieve this task.

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        String username = "test";
        String Password = "test2";
        String hostUrl= "";
        String casUrl= "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for calling the interface method you have to create object of the implemented class, and then you can refer to the function using that object.
example:

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,IServiceHandler {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ............
        ............
        ............
        CasAuthentication casAuthentication = new CasAuthentication(this);
        String expectedResult = casAuthentication.getTicketGrantingTicket(username, password, hostUrl, casUrl)

    }}
```

Comment: getting an error IserviceHandler is abstract ; cannot be instantiated

Comment: Since IServiceHandler is also an interface class. I cannot create a instance of interface class. Its throw me an error. How can i solve this issue.

Comment: @AnandaPrasadJaisy then you have to implement IServiceHandler in your activity, and pass the reference, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could just instantiate the class and call the method like this:

```
ICasAuthentication myClass = newCasAuthentication(new IServiceHandler());
myClass.getTicketGrandingTicket(...);
```

Comment: getting an error IserviceHandler is abstract ; cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing a [model class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027202/5754623) for this.