# How to properly initialize interface in Activity?

Tags: android, interface, initialization

I have this interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    void doSomething();
}
```

I am trying to initialize it in Main activity and I am trying to "send it" to second activity:

```
private SomeInterface someInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    someInterface = (SomeInterface) this;
    someInterface.doSomething();
}
```

I implemented interface into second activity.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface  {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

But this is not working, I am getting follwing error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.name/package.name.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to package.name.AppInterface
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Michalsx, you need to implement your interface in your activity class where you want to handle event of doSomething. check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/4862126

Comment: __MainActivity__ should implement __SomeInterface__ not __SeconActivity__

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the SomeInterface in your Activity class

`someInterface = (SomeInterface) this;`

here **this** refer to your Activity not the Interface as you haven't implemented it.
Hence ClassCastException

Comment: I see, sorry for my bad explanation. I want to use it for comunication between activities. I am trying to call "doSomething" in second activity. How to do that?

Comment: Use a model class refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027202/3022836](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027202/3022836)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:::

```
SomeInterface myListener=null;

public MainActivity(SomeInterface ml) {
    myListener = ml;
}
```

and implement it in your MainActivity

```
public void SomeMethod(){
//Some Code here;
myListener.doSomething("passed");
}
```

and then call it in Second

```
@Override
public void doSomething(String str) {
//you will get your passed text here in str.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[I used custom model suggested by Kunu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026515/how-to-use-interface-to-communicate-between-two-activities/19027202#19027202):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        CustomModel.getInstance().changeState(true);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements CustomModel.OnCustomStateListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "SecondActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        CustomModel.getInstance().setListener(this);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "stateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

First I launch second activity, after main, I kept this confusion order to keep it same as it was in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface {

  private SomeInterface someInterface;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // please add correct reference 
      someInterface = (SomeInterface) new SecondActivity();

      someInterface.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement the interface.. Try this

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface {

  private SomeInterface someInterface;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      someInterface = (SomeInterface) this;
      someInterface.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, sorry for my bad explanation. I want to use it for comunication between activities. I am trying to call "doSomething" in second activity. How to do that?

Answer (score -2):

I will take what you wanna do is to once doSomething in first activity changed, you second activity would recognize it.

Then you could try this

```
public Interface SomeInterface
{
   void doSomething(); // here you may pass in some para maybe you want to use it to communicate with other activties
}
```

then in the first activity you get the instance of the interface

```
 public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
    SomeInterface someInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    someInterface = (SomeInterface) this;
    someInterface.doSomething();
}
}
```

In the second activity implement the interface

```
public void SecondActivity implements SomeInterface
{
   @Override
   public void doSomething()
   {
      // here it will run once doSomething is called in first activity,and if the interface in first activity has params, it would be passed here
   }
}
```

Comment: give this error 'Activity cannot be cast to  callbackInterface'