# How can I communicate between parent and child activities in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener

I have three activities - activity A ,activity B ,activity C . Activity A is the launcher activity . From this activity , I go to activity B  .

The definition of activity B and activity C is as follows :

```
public class B extends C 
public abstract class C extends BaseActivity
```

Now I want to do something in activity B after completion of some task in activity C . I have searched in the google and stackoverflow . [This leads me to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027202/6379197)

But following the above answer the call of function stateChanged() takes a lot of time . Is there any faster way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Every `B` activity is a `C` activity. So if you define a method in `C` that is inherited i.e. the method is *public* or *protected* Or *package-private* with B in same package then override the method as following:

```
@Override 
protected void method (){
    super.method ();
    myTaskAfterSuperMethodReturns ();
}
```

If you are doing some async task better you define async task in class B.

Another  approach is define  `doSomething` in Class `C` as an obstract method and implement it in `B`. Call `doSomething` when your task is done. Making `doSomething` abstract will force `B` to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) Library to fire the event in Activity B when the task done in Activity C

Answer (score -1):

You can also access the method of MainActivity from another Activity like this:

MainActivity.class

```
private static MainActivity mInstance;

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
    return mInstance;
}
```

In Oncreate method initialize the instance

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mInstance = this;
}
```

creating method to use in next activity

```
@Override
public void showData(){
    //do something here
}
```

To access it just call from another activity

```
(MainActivity.getInstance()).showData()
```

Comment: Then, would not super class depend on subclass?

Comment: OP clearly mentioned the situation. Consider answering in that context.