# Pass information to a paused activity to call a method (Not UI update)

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

Scenerio:

**Activity A** opens **Activity B**. **Activity B** has some filters based on which the content of **Activity A** will change. To reduce waiting time for the users, I want to notify **Activity A** to start fetching the content as soon as there is a change on **Activity B**.

What would be the best way to achieve this without changing activity's structure ?

Comment: You can use interfaces. Just curious why are you using filters on another activity ?

Comment: use eventbus or RXJava for that.

Comment: @Umair That's a separate discussion and not an option at the moment. I thought about interfaces but do you have an idea how to use them in a good way ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya eventbus will require an architectural change. How do you propose RXJava be used ?

Comment: You can use eventbus easily. It not required more change.

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan what do you mean by using them in good way? :) .Interfaces are pretty easy to use or you can use local broadcast receivers.

Comment: @Umair I am talking about communication between 2 activities using interfaces.

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan please take a look at the second answer it's the cleanest way to do using interfaces:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026515/how-to-use-interface-to-communicate-between-two-activities

Comment: @Umair Yes, it will work but it uses a static object that will be attached to Activities.

Comment: Try using BroadcastReciever that listen on changes in Activity B then onReceive() will be called in Activity A and do what you want on it . I hope I understood your Q correctly and answered it as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a LocalBroadcastManager.
Register a LocalBroadCastManager in Activity A and send a message from Activity B. Unregister it upon exiting Activity A.

In Activity A:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
  mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("CUSTOM-EVENT_NAME"));

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // process the message here
      String data = intent.getStringExtra("intent-key")
    }
};
```

In Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("CUSTOM-EVENT_NAME");
intent.putExtra("intent-key","data");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```