# Is it possible to send a signal from an intent and recover it in another intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have 2 activities.. one is launched via deep links. MainActivity doesn't start DeeplinkActivity. How do I know from MainActivity when DeeplinkActivity finishes.

I have tried setting an intent filter programmatically. then added it to MainActivity then in DeeplinkActivity sendBroadcast.

I was unsuccessful since the broadcast recover method in MainActivity wasn't responding to broadcast sent from Deeplink via sendBroadcast(getIntent())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface, inside onDestroy() of DeepLink activity call the interface method and implement the method in MainActivity.
Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027202/7248394

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `putExtra()`
put this in your FirstActivity :

```
Intent intent  = new Intent (FirstActivity.this , SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("your key" , yourBooleanVariable) ;
FirstActivity.this.startActivity(intent) ;
```

And this code in Your Second Activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent() ;
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if(intent.hasExtra("your key")){
Boolean boolean = bundle.getBoolean();
}
```

you can put everything in a bundle with putExtra and get it from the bundle in the second Activity

Comment: You overlooked the fact that FirstActivity doesn't start second activity

Answer (score 0):

Both the Model and Broadcast method work.

I chose to use the Broadcast method much simpler

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReciever receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2) {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(getPackageName() + ".FOO_BAR"));
      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

> DeepLink

```
public class DeepLink extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(getPackageName() + ".FOO_BAR"));
    }
}
```